# How can resolve Error: "Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView" SharePoint 2010?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, webusercontrols

Following error comes when creating a WebPart In sharePoint 2010 Server.

> Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the user code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.900.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. at ListMenuSample.ListMenuSample.ListMenuSample.CreateChildControls() at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartWrapper.ExecuteHttpRequest(SPUserCodeWebPartHttpRequestContext webPartExecutionContext, SPUserCodeWebPartHttpResponse httpRequestResponse) at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartWrapper.Execute(SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

Comment: Can you provide code of your webpart cs file or at least CreateChildControls() procedure?

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the SharePoint 2010 server, what is the version number of the Microsoft.Sharepoint DLL in the GAC (windows\assembly)?  If somehow your code is specifically tied to version 14.900.00 and the version in the assembly is different then that may be your problem.

Also, just wanted to double check that you aren't deploying a copy of the Microsoft.SharePoint DLL with your solution, because that would be bad.